# stop a loop when someone types the number 0

Tags: java

With scanner, how can I stop a loop when someone types 0?
When some one doesn't type 0, the scanner input will show again and again.
I want to stop the loop with break.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ex1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.print("Enter any  number or enter 0 to stop: ");
            long x = input.nextLong();
        while (input.nextLong() == 0) {
            if (x== 0)
                break;
        } 
        }
    }
```

Comment: `while (input.nextLong() == 0)` => `while(true)` and then move the 2 lines asking for user input into that loop.

Answer (score 2):

You're looking for something like this:

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MyClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter any  number or enter 0 to stop: ");

        long x = 0;
        while ((x = input.nextLong()) != 0) {
            System.out.println("Try again! Your input was %l", x);
        } 
    }
}
```

You're never re-assigning the variable `x`, so your condition is always false.